# Auto-complete Email Addresses using Google API

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I am building a web app and want to auto-complete the email addresses. I am able to compose and send emails using [Gmail Scopes](https://mail.google.com/) and javascript. But how can I auto-complete the email addresses when typing the receiver's email addresses? I know I can use Google Contact API to achieve this, can anyone kindly point out how to do it and provide source code if possible. Please see the SS that shows what I need.

[image]

I am using **LAMP** stack and **JavaScript(jQuery)**

Comment: AFAIK, there is no feature in the API for this (also stated in this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/iLsrN23xF6g)). You can also check (star) the [reported feature request](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2975) to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

There's (currently, 2018) no built-in feature to provide auto-complete in the Gmail API.  You have to implement it yourself in your application.

You can use the [Google People](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/) or [Google Contacts](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/) APIs to get lists of candidate recipients.

You can also create candidate lists by downloading metadata on recently sent email messages.  This approach lets you prioritize auto-complete results by frequency and recency, which is a nice user experience.

Next, use a Javacsript auto-complete library (there are [many to choose from](https://www.google.com/search?ei=bI1tW_qtL5GyzwLV1pSYCQ&q=javascript%20autocomplete%20library&oq=javascript%20autocomplete%20library)) to implement your UI.